# ctest: Disable a set of labeled tests by default - but run them when explicitly targeted

Tags: cmake, ctest

I'd like to disable a set of tests by default, but be able to run them when explicitly targeted.

E.g. suppose I have a project with lots of fast-running unit tests that have been added via a `add_test(NAME SomeNameHere COMMAND SomeCommandHere)` command.  And suppose further that there are also a bunch of long-running integration tests that should be excluded from the default `ctest` run,  But it should be possible to run all integration tests with a single command when explicity targeted.

As a concrete example:

- `TestThatShouldAlwaysRun` - I'd like this to run when a user runs `$ ctest`
- `FooIntegrationTest`  - I'd like this to run *only* when a user runs `$ ctest --some-option-here integration`
- `BarIntegrationTest`  - I'd like this to run *only* when a user runs `$ ctest --some-option-here integration`

Here's a my attempt to achieve this.

```sh
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project (HOW_TO_RUN_DISABLED_TESTS NONE)
enable_testing()

# Add a fast running test
# This test should be run when a user runs: 'ctest'
add_test(NAME TestThatShouldAlwaysRun COMMAND echo 'I am always enabled')

# Add a long-running integration test
# This test should be run when a user runs: 'ctest --label-regex my_integration_tests'
add_test(NAME FooIntegrationTest COMMAND echo 'Foo integration test')
set_tests_properties(FooIntegrationTest PROPERTIES DISABLED True)
set_tests_properties(FooIntegrationTest PROPERTIES LABELS my_integration_tests)

# Add another long-running integration test
# This test should be run when a user runs: 'ctest --label-regex my_integration_tests'
add_test(NAME BarIntegrationTest COMMAND echo 'Bar integration test')
set_tests_properties(BarIntegrationTest PROPERTIES DISABLED True)
set_tests_properties(BarIntegrationTest PROPERTIES LABELS my_integration_tests)
```

Now, let's run this via

```sh
$ mkdir build
$ cd build/
$ cmake ..
$ ctest -V
```

As we can see in the output (posted below) `ctest` did exclude the integration tests (great!).

```
1: Test command: /bin/echo "'I" "am" "always" "enabled'"
1: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000
1: 'I am always enabled'
1/3 Test #1: TestThatShouldAlwaysRun ..........   Passed    0.00 sec
test 2
    Start 2: FooIntegrationTest
2/3 Test #2: FooIntegrationTest ...............***Not Run (Disabled)   0.00 sec
test 3
    Start 3: BarIntegrationTest
3/3 Test #3: BarIntegrationTest ...............***Not Run (Disabled)   0.00 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Label Time Summary:
my_integration_tests    =   0.00 sec*proc (2 tests)

Total Test time (real) =   0.05 sec

The following tests did not run:
      2 - FooIntegrationTest (Disabled)
      3 - BarIntegrationTest (Disabled)
```

But, I can not figure out how I can now, through `ctest`, run tests labeled with `my_integration_tests`.

```
ctest --label-regex my_integration_tests
Test project /path/to/code/example_repo/build
    Start 2: FooIntegrationTest
1/2 Test #2: FooIntegrationTest ...............***Not Run (Disabled)   0.00 sec
    Start 3: BarIntegrationTest
2/2 Test #3: BarIntegrationTest ...............***Not Run (Disabled)   0.00 sec
No tests were found!!!
```

Is there a way to run disabled tests when explicitly targeted?

I have explored other ways like

- Not disabeling the integration tests.  Then, when a user wants to run the fast running tests they need to specify `ctest --label-exclude my_integration_tests`.  Which isn't great.  That puts a burdon on everyone to remember this.  I'd like the options that's used the most (running only the fast-running tests) to be runnable via `ctest`.
- Not disableing the integration tests but provide the argument `CONFIGURATIONS my_integration_tests` to the `add_test` call.  But I think that way I am semantically misusing `CONFIGURATIONS`.  Also this doesn't allow me to run *only* the integration test when targeted.
- Add the integration tests via `add_custom_target`.  Also here I think I am misusing the API.  `add_custom_target` is meant for custom targets, not as a way to run test, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a simpler way to do this is just via a cmake configuration option.

```
# cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project (HOW_TO_RUN_DISABLED_TESTS NONE)
enable_testing()
add_test(NAME TestThatShouldAlwaysRun COMMAND echo 'I am always enabled')
if(BUILD_INTEGRATION_TESTING)
   add_test(NAME FooIntegrationTest COMMAND echo 'Foo integration test')
   add_test(NAME BarIntegrationTest COMMAND echo 'Bar integration test')
endif()
```

This is simple and also is more flexible, ie. enables addition of test dependent targets to be build (and setup (and ctest fixtures to be used)) for those tests. (I usually in projects see variables named like `SOMETHING_BUILD_TESTING` so it's similar to `BUILD_TESTING` cmake variable.)

Another idea I have is to use an environment variable and wrap the test in a script with `SKIP_RETURN_CODE` (or even without `SKIP_RETURN_CODE` and just return success if integration tests shouldn't be run):

```
add_test(NAME FooIntegrationTest 
        COMMAND sh -c "if [ \"\${RUN_INTEGRATION:-}\" ]; then echo 'Foo integration test'; else exit 127; fi"
        VERBATIM)
set_tests_properties(FooIntegrationTest PROPERTIES 
        SKIP_RETURN_CODE 127)
```

then:

```
$ ctest -V
....
2: Test command: /usr/bin/sh "-c" "if [ "${RUN_INTEGRATION:-}" ]; then echo 'Foo integration test'; else exit 127; fi" "VERBATIM"
2: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000
2/3 Test #2: FooIntegrationTest ...............***Skipped   0.01 sec
....
The following tests did not run:
      2 - FooIntegrationTest (Skipped)
```

but:

```
$ RUN_INTEGRATION=TRUE ctest -V
...
2: Test command: /usr/bin/sh "-c" "if [ "${RUN_INTEGRATION:-}" ]; then echo 'Foo integration test'; else exit 127; fi" "VERBATIM"
2: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000
2: Foo integration test
2/3 Test #2: FooIntegrationTest ...............   Passed    0.01 sec
...
```

Comment: I'd nevertheless be interested in an answer to: "Is there a way to run disabled tests when explicitly targeted?"  Do you happen to know the answer?

E.g. in a few projects I am using GoogleTest.cmake which marks disabled gtests as "ctest-disabled" https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/GoogleTest.cmake#L373

It would be useful in certain situations to run all disabled tests with a single ctest command.  Most projects disable certain tests because they might take too long to run, or rely on dependencies that might not be available on all machines.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with LABELS property.
Mark the tests that you always want to run as "GOLD" tests and always run ctest as  ctest -L GOLD.
Other tests that you want to disable by default can be categorized with other labels such as "EXPFAIL", "DISABLED" etc. And when you want to run those, you can use appropriate -L label.
This doesn't even require you to re-configure the tests. Configure once, and run what you want to run.

The only downside is that by default we have to use ctest -L "GOLD" instead of ctest.